# xampp-vm on mac cannot found the '/opt/lampp' directory after mounted this in stack manager

Tags: php, macos, xampp-vm

When I installed the 'New XAMPP with PHP 7.2.2 & 7.1.14' and followed steps in this tutorial [XAMPP-VM for Mac - tell us what you think](https://www.apachefriends.org/blog/new_xampp_20170628.html)
.At this time I can see the phpmyadmin at my localhost 8080 port, however, when try to change my working directory to the lampp. I got the err no such directory in /opt? Can anyone help?

[xampp lampp mount](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VIbo3.png)

[can not found /opt/lampp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E3Ehs.png)

[but the lampp file do existed in shared](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RKjXO.png)

Answer (score 5):

Like jayson said, clicking the button "Open Terminal" pops up a terminal that connects to the XAMPP-VM with SSH.

The folder "/opt/lampp" you are looking for is "inside" the VM, not in Mac.

Image: [image: Terminal Screenshot]

Answer (score 3):

open the xampp application -> general. select the open terminal button

Comment: Maybe adding a screenshot would help to make this more clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can mount it yourself (replace with your local IP):

```
hatem@Mac:/opt$ sudo mkdir lampp
hatem@Mac:/opt$ sudo mount -t nfs -o resvport,rw 192.168.64.2:/opt/lampp /opt/lampp
```

Then ls and you will find the entire lampp from the VM mounted locally.